# Lucidworks Fusion 4.1 transform result documents using Javascript query pipeline

Tags: java, solr, pipeline, solrcloud, lucidworks

How can I **transform solr response** using **JavaScript query Pipeline** in Lucidworks Fusion 4.1? For example I have the following response:

```
[ 
   { "doc_type":"type1",
     "publicationDate":"2018/10/10",
     "sortDate":"2017/9/9"},
   { "doc_type":"type2",
     "publicationDate":"2018/5/5",
     "sortDate":"2017/12/12"}]
```

And I need to change it with the following conditions:

If `doc_type = type1` then put `sortDate` in `publicationDate` and remove `sortDate`; else only remove `sortDate`

How can I manipulate with response? There is no documentation in official website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you cannot modify the Solr response.  All you can do is add to it.  So you could add a new block of JSON, include the "id" of the item and then list the fields and values you want to use in your UI.

Otherwise, you need to make the change in your Index Pipeline (as long as the value doesn't need to change based on the query).